# Get UDP connection statistics from IP Helper API (iphlpapi.dll)

Tags: c#, windows, udp, network-traffic, iphelper

I would like to count the bytes received and sent from specific UDP connections in Windows 10.

[This answer lists an approach to count bytes for specific TCP connections](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25650933/385513) using `GetPerTcpConnectionEStats()` from the IP Helper API (`iphlpapi.dll`). I would like to mirror this approach for UDP connections.

The IP Helper API provides UDP and TCP implementations for almost all functions (e.g., `GetTcpTable()`, `GetUdpTable()`), except the [documentation does not list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366071(v=vs.85).aspx) `GetPerUdpConnectionEStats()`. 
[This answer references the function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4826438/385513) nevertheless.

Is is possible to get counts of bytes received and sent from specific UDP connections with the IP Helper API?

Comment: The best place to start is www.pinvoke.net.  This webpage (from your link) : https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/bb485738.aspx uses the enum from pinvoke : https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Enums.MIB_TCP_STATE.  You can use following : https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/iphlpapi/GetExtendedTcpTable.html